# Adding Dropdown and Editable Field Types in Confluence Pages/template

Tags: jira, confluence, jira-plugin, confluence-rest-api, confluence-macros

I am currently using Confluence for a project and have created a space with several templates. In one of these templates, I need to incorporate a dropdown field and another editable field type. We have successfully used custom fields in Jira, but I'm unsure how to achieve this in a Confluence page or template. Can you suggest any plugins or alternative methods to accomplish this?

Adding Dropdown and Editable Field Types in Confluence Pages/template

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.